# How to mask a URL in a website?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to "mask" a URL. I have a subdomain that I do not want people to know about on my website. So what I am needing help with is this:

My website is: www.example.com

I have a subdomain: sub.example.com/test.php

When someone clicks on a link that points to sub.example.com/test.php, I do not want "sub.example.com/test.php" to show in the url bar. I would like for www.example.com to show instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to link to `sub.example.com/test.php`, change the link to something else, like `www.example.com/sub/test.php` or something. Then in your .htaccess file in the document root for `www.example.com` add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [L,P]
```

This will internally proxy any request for `www.example.com/sub/` to `sub.example.com`. So when someone requests http://www.example.com/sub/path/file.html, they really get http://sub.example.com/path/file.html except their URL address bar still has the example.com URL. You just need to make sure to change all of your links to sub.example.com to example.com/sub/