# Virtual pages in wordpress with post data

Tags: wordpress

I look for a function with allow me to have a virtual page which call a template page with POST data.

For exemple, when I write :

```
www.mysite.com/virtual-page
```

call

```
www.mysite.com/reel-page
with a post data
```

I would like user only see www.mysite.com/virtual-page in url bar.

Has someone any idea ?

I try with the following code which give only a redirection.

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    $url = trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
    if ($url == 'virtual-page')
    {
        //echo "tet";
        wp_redirect("reel-page");
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect');
```

Comment: It's possible to do `example.com/virtual/page`, would that work? But to load `reel-page` contents a theme/plugin template would have to deal with the output.

Comment: @brasofilo : In fact, I would like to have a custom url which load a template page with $POST data. I look for doing that with hook.- and not by wp-admin.

Comment: Where is the $_POST data coming from and how much info is it? Is it a form that opens this virtual page?

Comment: @brasofilo: it's not issued from form a form but can be defined in hook. For exemple $POST['target'] = '1' for one virtual page and $POST['target'] = '2' for another, this two pages had as target the reel template page (a $GET is also ok for me but I prefer $POST).

Comment: Maybe a simple [rewrite rule](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956015/1287812)? I was thinking of [endpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24331768/1287812) but if GET is not what you want...